# Having trouble with finding href html in web codes

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python.  Since I am new to it, I am not allowed to use Python's built in library's, except when told.  For this question, I am to find the individual href locations for "http://news.ycombinator.com/".  I have looked at a couple more answers here and I see that most people are told to use beautifulsoup.  I cannot use that.  I have been told to use lists and then to append those lists to find it.  Here is my code so far.  It is lousy for many reason, least of which is the fact that I have no idea what I am doing.

```
import urllib.request
page_list=[]
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://news.ycombinator.com/")
html=open(local_filename)
for line in html:
    page_list.append(line)
for k in range(len(page_list)):
    if '<a href' in page_list[k]:
        href_line=k
href_start = page_list[href_line].find('<a href')
href_end = page_list[href_line].find('</a')
print(page_list[href_start][href_start: href_end])
```

I know I need two lists to do the appending.  However, I have no idea how to do it since I am so new to Python.  I would love some help.

Comment: Have you had a look at their API : https://github.com/HackerNews/API ?

Comment: Just looked.  Sadly I don't really understand much of it cuz lots of it I haven't heard of yet.